# How to declare a variable of type "Date" in Angular

Tags: angular, date

What my Interface looks like:

```
export interface Isprit {
id?: string;
datum?: Date;
kmGefahren?: number;
kmStand?: number;
literGetankt?: number;
preis?: number;
langstrecke?: boolean;
```

Now i want to create an object from that interface:

```
  sprit: Isprit = {
datum: ???????????,
kmGefahren: 0,
kmStand: 0,
literGetankt: 0,
preis: 0,
langstrecke: false
```

How can I declare a variable of the type "Date"?

Comment: ...`new Date()`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use **`new Date()`** which will give you an date

```
sprit: Isprit = {
datum: new Date(),
kmGefahren: 0,
kmStand: 0,
literGetankt: 0,
preis: 0,
langstrecke: false
}
```